# Does spring-session supports Redis Cluster

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, spring-session, redis-cluster

Currently we are using redis stand alone for the spring session management.
We would like to use the redis cluster with spring session management.
Would like to understand on the configuration if cluster is supported.
Also does spring session data puts / gets the session data from the correct cluster end point?

- spring.session.store-type=redis
- spring.redis.cluster.nodes={}
- spring.redis.host=localhost
- spring.redis.port=6379
- spring.redis.password=pword